# MySQL lock and statements that lock rows using a unique index

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

In MySQL document [14.6.1 InnoDB Locking "Gap Locks"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html) section, it is said

> Gap locking is not needed for statements that lock rows using a unique
>   index to search for a unique row. ... For example, if
>   the `id` column has a unique index, the following statement **uses only an
>   index-record lock** for the row having id value 100 and ...
>
> `SELECT * FROM child WHERE id = 100;`
>
> If `id` is not indexed or has a
>   nonunique index, the statement **does lock the preceding gap**.

However, in the follow-up part, [14.6.3 Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-set.html), it is said

> SELECT ... FROM is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and **setting no locks** unless the transaction isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE.

It seems that the latter(no locks) conflicts with the the former(need a record or gap lock).

Do I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no contradiction here. The later statement refers that `SELECT ... FROM` does not lock anything because this is a `SELECT` without `WHERE` clause.
Furthermore, in the former, you are talking about a very specific lock which only prevents the INSERTing of records with specific key values (the "gap lock").